# AFNetworking 3.0 get request Swift3.0

Tags: swift, afnetworking

Have migrated code from swift 2 to swift 3. Getting error Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'value'. can anybody help me out `AFNetworking` with `Swift3`, totally stuck.

```
 let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

manager.get(
        ADS_URL,
        parameters: [],
        success: { (operation,responseObject) in
             self.loggedIn = responseObject.value(forKey: "success") as! Bool  // Error Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'value'


        },
        failure: { (operation,error) in
            sender!.setCMSError(error)
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 is very strict on types. 
You should downcast explicitly 
    responseObject 
from the default Any? to an NSDictionary in order to apply directly to the value under the 
    key ["success"].